# DFS algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I searched everywhere but I cannot comprehend the reason why the time complexity is O(V+E) and not O(V*E). For each vertices, we search every edges. So each vertex, will take O(E) time and if we do it for all vertices, it is O(V*E), in my opinion.
Sorry for that simple question but i really don't get it and I am new to algorithm.

Comment: You are using E for two things -- for the total number of edges, but also for the number of edges from a particular vertex. Each edge is traversed exactly once.

Comment: Thank you Paul, i finally got it. I still don't think the attached page had that answer. So again, thank you so much.